# Javascript parsing using webView returns different results

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

Im using the following code in order to get the HTML of a website (since the website uses javascript, I added this code):

```
wb_result.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wb_result.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");
wb_result.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        wb_result.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
    }
});


btn_click.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String mainPath = "https://merhav.nli.org.il/primo-explore/search?tab=default_tab&search_scope=Local&vid=NLI&lang=iw_IL&query=any,contains,הארי פוטר";
        wb_result.loadUrl(mainPath);
    }
} );


class MyJavaScriptInterface {

    private Context ctx;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).setTitle("HTML").setMessage(html)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();
    }

}
```

Now, the first time I run it after installing the app, it works well and displays a full long HTML that includes everything. However, if I run it again and again it displays some short version of the HTML.

I was thinking maybe the `webview` saves some data that might cause it not to load full data so I tried to use             `wb_result.clearCache( true );`  but it didnt work. Also tried:

```
 CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);         
 CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();        
 cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

Again didn't work. It seems like it randomly returns the full HTML.

Is there any reason that I get different results for different runs?

Thank you